# Can different subfields have the same Minimal Polynomial?

Tags: galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am trying to see if different subfields (of $F(\alpha)$ containing $F$) can have the same minimal polynomial?

I'm hoping that the answer is no, so that if two subfields do have the same minimal polynomial, then they must be the same subfield!

Edited to add in the whole question:

Let $F(\alpha) : F$ be a simple algebraic extension.  Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be intermediate fields (that is, subfields of $F(\alpha)$ containg $F$).  Prove that if $\alpha$ has the same minimal polynomial over $E_1$ and $E_2$, then $E_1 = E_2$.

Comment: Subfields don't have minimal polynomials, elements of field extensions do.

Comment: In my paperwork they are referred to as Intermediate Fields (that is, subfields of $F(\alpha)$ containing $F$). And I have to prove that if $\alpha$ has the same minimal polynomial over $E_1$ and $E_2$ then $E_1 = E_2$

Comment: @Santiago - I have updated the post with the entire question.  Are you able to help me with it now?

Comment: There is something strange about this question, int that "same minimal polynomial" is comparing polynomials with coefficients in _a priori_ different fields (even though it is claimed they then must be equal). Such a comparison would imply that the coefficients lie in $E_1\cap E_2$, but in general they won't.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not clear, since subfields do not have minimal polynomials. I believe that your question is something along these lines:

"Given $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$, two algebraic extension fields of $F$, and knowing that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is the same as the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F$, can I conclude that $F(\alpha)=F(\beta)$?"

I believe that the answer to this question is no. Consider the following polynomial:

$$x^3-2=(x-\sqrt[3]2)(x-\sqrt[3]2\omega)(x-\sqrt[3]2\omega^2)$$

where $\omega$ in the third root of unity. Notice that none of the roots belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. Also this polynomial is irreducible in $Q[X]$ by Eisenstein criterion. Being monic, it is a minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2$ and $\sqrt[3]2\omega.$ But $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]2] \neq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]2\omega]$, since one field extension contains complex numbers and the other one does not.

So,the extensions are not the same. But are they isomorphic? What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, @Paquarian, my question wasn't very clear (it was my attempt to summarise!) I have updated the post with the actual question that I am trying to answer - are you able to help with it?

Comment: It’s now clear that your (and my) interpretation of the question is not in accord with OP’s intention. I gave you a +1 even though your good answer is not a help for helping OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can.  Example: Let p(x) be an irreducible cubic over $F$ with three roots $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$.  The three fields $F(r_1)$, $F(r_3)$, $F(r_3)$ will be distinct, and p(x) will be the minimal polynomial for all of them.  And they will all be common subfields of the spliting field of p(x) [$F(r_1,r_2,r_3)$, which is also representable as $F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$].

*[note: this is a slight generalization of the answer by @Paquarian]*

Comment: Hey, can you remind me why it is the case that the splitting field can be represented as a simple extension? In other words, why $F(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ can be represented as $F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$?

Comment: @Paquarian: by Artin's theorem on primitive element?

Comment: That's right, thanks!

Comment: However, the question is about the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over different subfields (which could be the $F(r_i)$), not about the minimal polynomial of the $r_i$ over $F$. You need to find $\alpha$ and compute its minimal polynomials if this is to be an example.